Am I understanding memory ordering models correctly? (cont'd)
This is a follow-up of this question. I have updated the code to incorporate some of the ideas pointed out by Peter Cordes.

My threads should be doing actual parallel work (now it takes time to the producer to prepare "non-trivial" units for the next bucket)
The consumer checks and sets bucket_full only once per bucket, then it works on the units. This should now let the compiler put bucket in a register because there is no sync between accesses to it.
printf shouldn't be a problem, as bucket is now a static global.
Yes, this is only a learning exercise.

Questions:

When setting the "no more buckets" flag, I have to reset the value of empty at every loop so that if bucket_full did not match empty, then the overwriting made by atomic_compare_exchange_weak() doesn't inadvertently break the while loop at the second iteration. I find that to be a little cumbersome. Am I using the wrong tool to signal "no more buckets"?
I think I am actually getting parallel work (if I play with the arguments given to important_stuff I can see the time overlapping). Is that correct?
I think there is no data race. Is that the case?

Code:
The function important_stuff is simply a dummy timer to control whether the producer or consumer take more or less time in doing their job.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define tot_buckets 10
#define units_per_bucket 12

static int bucket = 0;
static _Atomic int bucket_full = 0;

// some delay to simulate work. h={0,99}
static inline void important_stuff(int h){
    struct timespec t = {0,h*10000000};
    nanosleep(&t,NULL);
}

void *producer(void *arg){
    int units_cumulator = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<tot_buckets; ++i){
        // get more units (parallel work)
        while(units_cumulator < units_per_bucket){
            important_stuff(15);
            units_cumulator += 1;
        }
        // wait for "empty bucket" signal
        while(atomic_load_explicit(&bucket_full, memory_order_acquire))
            sched_yield();
        // fill bucket
        bucket = units_cumulator;
        units_cumulator = 0;
        printf("\n[b%-2d:%2d]", i+1, bucket);
        fflush(stdout);
        //signal "bucket is full"
        atomic_store_explicit(&bucket_full, 1, memory_order_release);
    }
    // signal "no more buckets"
    int empty;
    do{
        empty = 0;
    }while(!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&bucket_full, &empty, -1));
    return arg;
}

void *consumer(void *arg){
    int tmp_bf;
    while(1){
        // wait for "bucket is full" signal
        while(!(tmp_bf=atomic_load_explicit(&bucket_full, memory_order_acquire)))
            sched_yield();
         // exit if no more buckets
        if(tmp_bf == -1)
            break;
        // work on the current bucket (parallel work)
        while(bucket--){
            important_stuff(20);
            printf(" %d", bucket);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        // signal "bucket is empty"
        atomic_store_explicit(&bucket_full, 0, memory_order_release);
    }
    return arg;
}

int main(){
    pthread_t t0, t1;
    pthread_create(&t0, NULL, consumer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, producer, NULL);
    pthread_join(t0, NULL);
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}


Compiling with:
gcc -std=c11 -pthread -O1 -g -fsanitize=thread -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors main.c -o main


If the answer in the first question wasn't sufficient, you should ask for clarification there, not post a new question. If it was sufficient and prompted a further question, you should accept the answer there.

@onlycparra Why struct timespec t = {0,h*10000000}; and not struct timespec t = {h*10000000, 0};?  Best to not rely on assumed struct order and use struct timespec t = {.tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec h*10000000L};.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Fair point. Given that important_stuff is just an accessory to the topic of the question, I just wanted to keep it small; but your comment makes sense. Thanks
